# Keeping certain html in an xpath query or retrieving original html from xpath query

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am using `xpath` technology to extract text from articles. What I want to do is query for the text and if certain tags (notice plural) exist I want to keep the tags and html in tact. **Another solution is to retrieve the original html from an xpath query and I can process it via php.**

Here's an example of an article:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <p>Some content</p>
                <blockquote>Some blockquote</blockquote>
                <embed src="someembed source"></embed>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I'm looking for is:

- Some content (from the p tags)
- `<blockquote>Some blockquote</blockquote>`
- `<embed src="someembed source"></embed>`
- `<br/>`

My xpath isn't designed to handle anything right now but the `<p>` tags.

```
$xpath = '//div[@id="main"]//div[@id="content]//p';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me interpret your question this way: you want to detect all occurences of `//div[@id="main"]//div[@id="content]` that also have the specific combination of child tags that you mentioned.

You can select these `div` occurences using the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@id="main"]//div[@id="content" and p and blockquote and embed and br]
```

If you just want the child nodes you could also write:

```
//div[@id="main"]//div[@id="content" and p and blockquote and embed and br]/*
```